# How to set default value of integer field to id() in app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to set default value of field in data model to id() of the data model?

something like

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    myID = db.IntegerProperty(default=self.id())
    desc = db.StringProperty()
```

Comment: I hope you have a genuine use for this and aren't really trying to do what you've written here?

Comment: yes, the code was managing the id within application but now the need arose to post/update model from web service. also the id is being consumed by other client applications and i do not want to disturb the code.

Comment: But then, just retrieve the ID. Don't store the ID again. Or am I still misunderstanding something?

Comment: id is consumed by other client apps which are not aware app engine datastore

Comment: Then send the ID! Don't store it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The default you're setting there is in a class variable, and will be the same for all instances created after the class definition is read. If `self.id()` actually made sense in this context (it doesn't; `self` is undefined), you'd be getting something like the id of the class, and assigning it as the default to all new instances.

The id isn't actually assigned to the entity until it is written to the datastore, so you can't, in principle, know what it is at the time of instantiation. You can set a property to the id *after* you've written the entity, but you almost certainly don't really want to do this anyway.

Comment: ok, get it, thx. Is it possible to create a callback like function which can be associated with default=mycall()? or do i need to override put() in which the model is saved once and then again with the id() assigned to field?

Comment: @dhaval, Why are you trying to add the `id` as a property when the id is already available as part of the objects' key?

Comment: @adam id is passed around to other applications and the model is now required to be automatically updated via web service, so need for the id to be autocreated in the field because web service clients will not know the last saved id.

Comment: @dhaval: if you fetch the entity to send it to another application, you already have the key, and therefore the ID. There's no reason to store the ID in the entity as a separate property, although you can certainly break out the ID into a separate field of the data you send over the wire to the other application.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can query by ID like this:

```
entity = MyModel.get_by_id(123)
entities = MyModel.get_by_id([123,456,789])
```

Storing an extra copy of the ID inside the entity is almost certainly unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways (subclassing db.Model and overriding the properties that hold the key, creating a custom property class to override default_value) but they make me feel dirty and suffer from a few side effects.

If I really did have a use for something like this (and I really can't think of one) I would make a special `create` method for my Model and use that to **pre-allocate the ids before creation**.

```
class BadModel(db.Model):
    my_id = db.IntegerProperty()

    @classmethod
    def create(model, **kwargs):
        id = db.allocate_ids(db.Key.from_path(model.kind(), 1),1)[0]
        kwargs['key'] = db.Key.from_path(model.kind(), id)
        kwargs['my_id'] = id
        return model(**kwargs)


>> e = BadModel.create()
>> e.my_id
2039
```

Comment: Sorry for the strange intro, just trying to put across that although i've answered, it's probably a bad idea and an alternative solution to whatever the real problem is should be explored.